# Navigate to the screen when Tab on BottomTabNavigator is pressed

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I would like to navigate to the screen when the particular tab on the BottomTabNavigator is pressed.

Normally, when the tab is pressed, it navigates to the configured screen automatically.  But I don't want to have that behaviour.  I want to hide the bottom tab on that screen and provide **back** feature in the top bar too.  I normally use `navigation.navigate('routeName')` in ReactNavigationStack screens.  But I don't know how/where to write this code in the BottomTabNavigator configuration.

For example, I've got the following 5 tabs in the bottom bar.  I want to navigate to **AddNewScreen** when **Add** button is pressed.  I don't know where to put that onPress event.  I tried to put it under `options` and `BottomTab.Screen`.  But still no luck.

[image]

I tried to intercept **onPress** event to use `navigation.navigate`.  But it's not even hit and it always opens the AddNewScreen with the tab bar.

```
<BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        initialParams="Home Params"
        options={{
          title: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-home" iconType="ion" />,
        }}
      />      
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="AddNew"
        component={AddNewScreen}        
        options={{
          title: 'Add',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-add-circle" iconType="ion" 
          onPress={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e)
          }} />,    
        }}
      />
</BottomTab.Navigator>
```

The Add new screen is always opened with the bottom tab bar.

[image]

**Questions**:

1. Is there anyway to navigate to specific screen when the tab is
   pressed?
2. Is there anyway to hide the bottom tab bar on that Add New
   Screen?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Update:

The Navigation library v6 supports the [Listener](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#listeners-prop-on-screen) feature that can be used

```js
<Tab.Screen
  name="Chat"
  component={Chat}
  listeners={{
    tabPress: e => {
      // Prevent default action
      e.preventDefault();

      //Any custom code here
      alert(123);
    },
  }}
/>;
```

You can have a custom functionality in the bottom toolbar using the tabbar button. The code would be like below

```js
<Tab.Screen
  name="Settings2"
  component={SettingsScreen}
  options={{
    tabBarButton: props => (
      <TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={() => alert(123)} />
    ),
  }}
/>
```

This would render a normal bottom tab bar button but the onclick would show the alert, you can replace the code with your navigate or any other code you need.
Also the 'SettingsScreen' component can be a dummy component returning null.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I use `props.navigation`, it tells me that navigation is `undefined`.
`tabBarButton` seems to not have `navigation` object, how can we retrieve it ?

Comment: you will have to pass a function to options which will receive the navigation as a param

Comment: thanks!! it works by doing `options={({navigation}) => {
          return {
            tabBarButton: () => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Market')}>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
          };
        }}`

Comment: thank you for this solutions. You cannot find it this easy in the docs. x

Answer (score 15):

You can have a custom functionality

```html
 <Tab.Screen
      name="Add"
      component={View}
      listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
        tabPress: (e) => {
          // Prevent default action
          e.preventDefault();

          // Do something with the `navigation` object
          navigation.navigate("PhotoNavigation"); // Here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        },
      })}
    />
<Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
```

Comment: This is the official solution. Thumbs up!